# How to programmatically refresh the Notification Area Icons page

Tags: c++, vb.net, windows-7, windows-explorer

Background:
If you look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
in the bottom you will see:

> **Note**  When an application is uninstalled, its notification area icon can still appear to the user as an option in the Notification Area Icons page in the Control Panel for up to seven days. However, any changes made there will have no effect.

And yes, when you uninstall application the icon is still there in the "Notification Area Icons page" until you kill Explorer.exe and restart it - this is the problem I want to solve.

You can get to the "Notification Area Icons page" (in Windows 7) by : right click the taskbar > Properties > Customize

So what I want to do is to programmatically delete icon from that list or even delete all of the icons and then lets Windows to recreate them when you reopen that list page (this can be done by deleting the `PastIconsStream` and `IconStreams` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify`)

But again, the problem is that you only see the results **after** you kill and restart Explorer.exe - I assume that when you restart explorer.exe it rebuild the list but this time with the right icons (i.e does not include the icons from uninstalled apps).

So to make things simpler, I will ask this:
How do I programmatically make explorer refresh the 'Notification Area Icons page list' after I delete  `PastIconsStream` and `IconStreams` without killing/restarting explorer.exe and without restarting/logoff so that list will not include uninstalled applications icons?

Comment: There is no supported way of doing this.

Comment: Is there an unsupported way to do that?

Comment: My software cleans unreferenced registry, temp files ... and i want it to delete unnecessary icons from notification are as well and killing explorer for that is not something i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing Windows to rebuild its internal icon cache should do the trick.

To do so, you need to:

- Change the `Shell Icon Size` parameter in the registry
- Send a `HWND_BROADCAST` to notify that a UI setting has changed
- Restore the default `Shell Icon Size` value (otherwise the whole Windows UI will be messed up)
- Re-send the broadcast message again

Here's a demonstration code (unfortunately) written in VB6 (not VB.NET):

```
Private Sub RebuildIconCache()

    Dim IconSize As Integer
    Dim r As Long

    IconSize = QueryValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics", "Shell Icon Size")
    SetKeyValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics", "Shell Icon Size", CStr(IconSize - 1)

    SendMessageTimeout HWND_BROADCAST, _
                        WM_SETTINGCHANGE, _
                        SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS, _
                        0&, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, _
                        10000&, r

    DoEvents

    If IconSize < 32 Then IconSize = 32
    SetKeyValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics", "Shell Icon Size", CStr(IconSize)

    SendMessageTimeout HWND_BROADCAST, _
                        WM_SETTINGCHANGE, _
                        SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS, _
                        0&, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, _
                        10000&, r

End Sub
```